# Why doesn't this code post the selected option on my screen?

Tags: php, html, select, post, submit

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']){
    $myvalue=$_POST['sub1'];
    echo $myvalue;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='test322.php' method='POST'>
           <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
        </form>
        <select id='sub1' name='sub1'>
            <option value="fsd1">dssdds1</option>
            <option value="fsdff2">dssfddds2</option>
            <option value="fsdff3">dssfddds3</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hello all,
could anyone tell me why this code doesn't post the selected option on my screen? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your `select` element is not part of the form.

Comment: what do you get if you do var_dump($_POST);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the end-tag of `</form>` it is way to high.
Put it under the `</select>` and you will be happy ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $myvalue=$_POST['sub1'];
    echo $myvalue;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='test322.php' method='POST'>
<select id='sub1' name='sub1'>
            <option value="fsd1">dssdds1</option>
            <option value="fsdff2">dssfddds2</option>
            <option value="fsdff3">dssfddds3</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
            </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it does, but it's above the select element

Comment: <form>, <select> and then <input type="submit">

Answer (score 0):

The `select` element is not the part of you form.

Move the closing tag of form i.e. `</form>` after `</select>`

Answer (score 0):

There’s some mistakes in your code:

1) All data that you need to send in your code needs to be between  tags. So, your select  isn’t.

2) To get your POST data, just do with $_POST.

```
<?php
if ($_POST){
    $myvalue = $_POST['sub1'];
    echo $myvalue;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action='test322.php' method='POST'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
            <select id='sub1' name='sub1'>
                    <option value="fsd1">dssdds1</option>
                    <option value="fsdff2">dssfddds2</option>
                    <option value="fsdff3">dssfddds3</option>
                </select>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` was not part of your `form`. Try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $myvalue=$_POST['sub1'];
    echo $myvalue;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='lol.php' method='POST'>
            <select id='sub1' name='sub1'>
                <option value="fsd1">dssdds1</option>
                <option value="fsdff2">dssfddds2</option>
                <option value="fsdff3">dssfddds3</option> 
            </select>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
        </form>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the select elements in your form by moving the `</form>`:

```
    <form action='test322.php' method='POST'>


        <select id='sub1' name='sub1'>
            <option value="fsd1">dssdds1</option>
            <option value="fsdff2">dssfddds2</option>
            <option value="fsdff3">dssfddds3</option>
            </select>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
           </form>//add this tag
```

and you need to check for `POST` value like so:

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
{
    $myvalue=$_POST['sub1'];
    echo $myvalue;
}
```

Comment: The closing form tag existed orignally

Comment: Correct, however, 'You need to close you form tag' is not the same as 'Your closing form tag is in the wrong place'. Even more so when you have included 'add this tag' in your answer, when the tag existed originally.

Comment: It's been changed. Hope that helps clear up any confusion.